# how to use sessions in generating invoice with tcpdf and php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, tcpdf, fpdf

Here user can order their items and after confirmation of order they can download invoice file. After a quick Google I know about fpdf and tcpdf.but my question is how to create unique users invoice pdf through tcpdf and php?

[This is my cart page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC5CE.png)

[success page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxJwe.png)

[image: error in generating pdf]

> `

```html
<?php  
require 'common.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    header('location: index_bootstrap.php');
}

 function fetch_data()  
 {  
      $output = '';  
       $sum = 0;
       $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
 $query = "SELECT items.price AS Price, items.id, items.name AS Name FROM users_items JOIN items ON users_items.item_id = items.id WHERE users_items.user_id='$user_id'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query)or die($mysqli_error($con));
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
                            ?>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Item Number</th>
                                    <th>Item Name</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    $sum+= $row["Price"];
                                    $id = $row["id"] . ", ";
                                    echo "<tr><td>" . "#" . $row["id"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Name"] . "</td></tr>";
                                }
                                $id = rtrim($id, ", ");
                                echo "<tr><td></td><td>Total</td><td>Rs " . $sum . "</td><td></tr>";
                                ?>
                            </tbody>
                            <?php
                        } else {
                            echo "Add items to the cart first!";
                        }
       
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {       
      $output .= '<tr>  
                          <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["Name"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["Price"].'</td>  
                           
                     </tr>  
                          ';  
      }  
      return $output;  
 }  
 if(isset($_POST["create_pdf"]))  
 {  
      require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');  
      $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);  
      $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
      $obj_pdf->SetTitle("Export HTML Table data to PDF using TCPDF in PHP");  
      $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
      $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
      $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
      $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
      $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
      $obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '5', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
      $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
      $obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);  
      $obj_pdf->AddPage();  
      $content = '';  
      $content .= '  
      <h3 align="center">Export HTML Table data to PDF using TCPDF in PHP</h3><br /><br />  
      <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">  
           <tr>  
                <th width="5%">id</th>  
                <th width="30%">Name</th>  
                <th width="10%">Price</th>  
                
           </tr>  
      ';  
      $content .= fetch_data();  
      $content .= '</table>';  
      $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);  
      $obj_pdf->Output('sample.pdf', 'I');  
 }  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>TCPDF in PHP</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />            
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center">TCPDF in PHP</h3><br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr>  
                               <th width="5%">ID</th>  
                               <th width="30%">name</th>  
                               <th width="10%">price</th>  
                               
                          </tr>  
                     <?php  
                     echo fetch_data();  
                     ?>  
                     </table>  
                     <br />  
                     <form method="post">  
                          <input type="submit" name="create_pdf" class="btn btn-danger" value="Create PDF" />  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

this is code for pdf.php.and output contains mysql error.how to fix this

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Paste it here in code formatting.

Comment: Hi, i think you have to replace :$query = "SELECT items.price AS Price, items.id, items.name AS Name FROM users_items JOIN items ON users_items.item_id = items.id WHERE users_items.user_id='$user_id'"; by $query = "SELECT items.price AS Price, items.id, items.name AS Name FROM users_items JOIN items ON users_items.item_id = items.id WHERE users_items.user_id='".$user_id."'";

Comment: it does not working

Comment: This looks like a variable scope issue. In your `fetch_data()` function the variable `$con` is not defined/known which is resulting in the errors you are seeing in your PDF. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and) for more details.